# Register new user on Devexpress xaf asp

Tags: authentication, devexpress, xaf

We are trying using devexpress xaf framework to develop a system but We couldn't provide a new user to register on the system. we tried their example from
OBSOLETE - How to manage users (register a new user, restore a password, etc.) from the logon form in ASP.NET.we have successfully run the  the system on the example,  but on the register window says protected content and cannot enter User Name, Password and Email.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this old example is no longer recommended.
Anyway, you can customize your code as described at https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T705146/e4037-register-and-forget-password-functionality-for-the-web-for-v18-2-4 - this will help you avoid this behavior.